# T-SQL return amount from previous 5 weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, return

I have a table with the following information:

[image]

I'm using SSMS to create a "Goal" column that will use the `TotalAmt` from 5 weeks ago. Is there a way to return the total amount from 5 weeks ago?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Five weeks is 35 days (5 * 7 = 35).. The displayed values are not that far apart (03/24/2018 is not 35 days away from 04/21/2018). It's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: I think it is 4 weeks

Comment: @Rhumborl: That's not what the question asks. The poster should edit to make it clear. The desired output does not match the question text. This is not a *"Guess what I might really be asking" and answer site*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `LEAD` windows function can help you do that.

```
SELECT *,LEAD(Totle,4,0) OVER (ORDER BY Begin_date desc,EndDate desc) 'Goal Amt'
FROM T
```

[LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/152f7/4*

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm a big fan of `lead()`, I think the more sensible method is `lag()`:

```
select lag(total, 4) over (order by begin_date)
```